# solving nonlinear equations in Octave

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I am new to Octave and would like to know how to solve nonlinear equation. Here is an example equation

```
x^4-16x^3+61x^2-22x-12=0
```

Update:

```
w+x+y+1=3

2w+3x+4y+5=10

w-x+y-1=4
```

thanks

Comment: Did you try to [Google](http://goo.gl/BvPcBb) this first? Many good answers come up, such as [this one](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hanson/Octave/OctaveNonlinearEG.html)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) to get the solution closest to a given `x0` (well, not necessarily  closest, but the first one found):

This should work:

```
x0 = 0;
f = @(x) x^4 - 16*x^3 + 61*x^2 - 22*x - 12;
fzero(f,x0);
ans =  0.76393
```

Also, you should check out [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/roots.html), to get all the solutions of a polynomial.

```
x = [1 -16 61 -22 -12];  % The coefficients of your polynomial
y = roots(x)
y = 
   10.29150
    5.23607
    0.76393
   -0.29150
```

Ok, so I'll answer the second question anyway:

```
x = [1 1 1; 2 3 4; 1 -1 1]; % Coefficients of w, x and y
y = [2; 5; 5];              % [3-1; 10-5; 4+1]

b = x\y
b =
   2.2500
  -1.5000
   1.2500
```

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how you printed ans =  0.76393?

Comment: The OP referred to Octave, not Matlab, in the title (even though the question was tagged both) so shouldn't you link to Octave's documentation? Also, you mention `fslove` but then use the more appropriate (as this is a 1-D problem) `fzero`.

Comment: @DotNet Instead of typing `fzero(f,x0);`, type `fzero(f,x0);` without the `;`.
@RobertP. You mention `fsolve` in your answer but you `fzero` in yoru code, is that intentional?

Comment: @am304, no, that was not intentional! Thanks for noting... I changed it to `fzero`. I see you answered with `fsolve` before me, so I'll skip that in my answer. =)

Comment: @horchler: I'm used to the MATLAB documentation, and feel that it is usually very good also for Octave. But I guess it would be more appropriate in this case, yes... =)

Comment: @RobertP. Thanks for your help. I also have another query what about solving a system? as in the update

Comment: @DotNet: As that is a different question, please do one of the following: try to find an answer to it on SO or google. If you can't find it, please ask it as a separate question. (Check out \ ) =)

Answer (score 2):

[`fsolve`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/fsolve.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: As horlchler mentioned, `fzero` is more appropriate for a 1-D problem: http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/fzero.html